# Pycharm: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I'm trying to executing (with Pycharm) some [examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) in python using self contained sparks applications.

I installed pyspark using:

```
pip install pyspark
```

According to the web of the example, it should be just enough to execute it with:

```
python nameofthefile.py
```

But I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
    ... 23 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/PoC/Databricks.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Databricks").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 349, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 298, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

What could be wrong?

---

> EXTRA

According to the post where you can find the solution,for my case I had to change from jdk-11 to jdk1.8.

Now I can run the example code, but with an error (which does not prevent it from running)

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2019-01-24 08:46:16 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
```

[Here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html) is the solution of this `Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe`

Resuming, to solve this second problem, you just need to define HADOOP_HOME and PATH environment variables in Control Panel so any Windows program would use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

I had a similar issue, which I resolved by changing my JAVA_HOME environment variables configuration.
You may either manually add a new user environment variable JAVA_HOME linking to the path of you Java Development Kit (something "C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_121", or "C:/Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_121" if it is installed in "Program Files (x86)" on your Windows).

You may also try something like this at the beginning of your python code:

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_121"
```

(or, again, "C:/Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_121" if your JDK is installed under "Program Files (x86)"

---

Longer answer:
Independently of Pyspark, did you install Spark binaries (with hadoop included) ?
You also need to install a compatible java development kit (JDK) (java 8+ from Spark 2.3.0).
You also need to configure user environment variables such as:
JAVA_HOME with the path to the java development kit
SPARK_HOME with the path to the SPARK binaries
HADOOP_HOME with the path to the hadoop binaries

You may do something like this from python:

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:/Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_121"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/path/to/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

Then I recommend to use findspark (which you can install wich pip install findspark): https://github.com/minrk/findspark

You can then use it like this:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Especially if you are on Windows, JAVA_HOME should be something like:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

And, "If JDK is installed under \Program Files (x86), then replace the Progra~1 part by Progra~2 instead."

Details can be found here for installation on Windows (it is for jupyter but the installation of spark and pyspark is the same):
https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/

I hope it helps,
Good luck and have a nice day/evening!

Comment: Thank you! I "follow" the short way and the problem was I was using jdk-11 instead of jdk 1-8. Now I can execute it and I have the result of the example. Also I have an exception(which does not prevent it from running) but i'm not sure if is due any of your steps of your long answer. I have attached to the main post